# Mapping an array of scalars in Doctrine 2 ORM

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, associations

Is it possible to map an array of scalars to a property in a Doctrine entity without creating a separate entity for the items in the array?

The situation is as follows:

- The entity has a property which is an array of strings.
- The data must be stored in a separate table, with a one-to-many type relationship.
- Using Doctrine's `array` type is not possible, because it uses PHP serialization, and this data must be simple to read for both PHP and non-PHP systems.

It seems to me like overkill to have an entity. Is there another solution?

Comment: Isn't this a bit like asking if you can join 2 tables using SQL without using a join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The data must be stored in a separate table

Then you want a separate entity.

> with a one-to-many type relationship

Entities handle this for you.

> The entity has a property which is an array of strings

You'll have an array collection of entities by default, and can easily write your own getter method to return a simple array of strings if necessary.

> It seems to me like overkill to have an entity.

No. It's not.

> Is there another solution?

Not without reinventing the wheel. Doctrine has everything you need, ready to go. Just use it like it's designed. Create a separate entity and define the relationship.